# specs2 - how to use the same variable inside around and inside the test itself?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, specs2

I am using specs2 as my test framework.
I want to generate a uniq key that will be available in the test itself.

```
def around[R: AsResult](r: => R): Result = {
   val uniqueToken = before()
   try AsResult(r)(uniqueToken)
   finally after(uniqueToken)
}

"foo" should {
   "bar" in {
     do something with uniqueToken
   }
}
```

Couldn't find any good way to do it..
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this

```
class MySpec extends Specification with ForEach[Token] {
  "foo" should {
     "do something" in { token: Token =>
        ok
     }
  }

  def foreach[R : AsResult](f: Token => R): Result = {
    val token = createToken

    try AsResult(f(token))
    finally cleanup(token)
  }
}
```

This is documented [here](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.5/org.specs2.guide.Contexts.html#foreach).

Answer (score 0):

You should get the general idea from this pseudocode:

```
class Around[R: AsResult](r: => R) {
   val uniqueToken = before()

   try AsResult(r)(uniqueToken)
   finally after(uniqueToken)
}

"foo" should {
   "bar" in new Around(r) {
     do something with uniqueToken
   }
}
```